# swap with non-const reference parameters

Tags: c++, swap

I got [Error] invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'float&' from an rvalue of type 'float'

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(float &a, float &b){
    float temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
main()
{
    int a=10, b=5;
    swap((float)a, (float)b);
    printf("%d%d",a,b);
}
```

Comment: `(float)a` creates an rvalue, and an rvalue cannot bind to an lvalue reference. You would need to declare `a` and `b` as floats in order for `swap(a, b)` to work.

Comment: `main()` needs to be `int main()`.

Comment: `void swap(float *a, float *b)` `swap((float*)&a, (float*)&b);` Why anyone would use a `float` instead of an `int` in this case is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlad is correct, why cast to `float`? Use `int` for all values. However, if you have some reason for doing it that way, you must be consistent in your `cast` and `references`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(float *a, float *b){
    float temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a=10, b=5;
    swap((float*)&a, (float*)&b);
    printf("\n%d%d\n\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/floatcast

510
```

When you pass an address to a function, it must take a `pointer` as an argument. Thus `void swap(float *a,..` When you need a `reference` to an address of a variable (to pass as a `pointer`), you use the `address of` operator `&`. When you handle values passed as a `pointer`, in order to operate on the `values` pointed to by the `pointer` you must `dereference` the pointer using the `*` operator. Putting all that together, you get your code above. (much easier to just use `int`... `:)`

---

**C++ Refernce**

If I understand what you want in your comment, you want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

// using namespace std;

void swap(float& a, float& b){
    float temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a=10, b=5;
    swap ((float&)a, (float&)b);
    std::cout << std::endl << a << b << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/floatref

510
```

Comment: It's working...  but how will it be if I want to use swap(float &, float &)?

<sorry.. my English is not good>

Comment: I'm confused. You cannot use `float &`, because after you use `&` you no longer have a `float` you have `an address of a float` which is a `pointer to a float` so you must use `float *`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: It's a C++ reference.

Comment: @DracudaKid Uugh -- I was right the first time **I'm confused**. What do you mean by `float &`? Are you talking about wanting to `cast` something that way, or take the address of something, or use it in some other way? Thank you Benjamin.

Comment: By `float&`, he means he wants to take a reference to a float. A C++ reference is similar to a pointer, but acts more like an alias. That is to say, usage of a reference is syntactically identical to usage of the referent. It allows you to do something like `swap(a, b)`, and it will actually swap the values of `a` and `b`, instead of having to do `swap(&a, &b)`. See the first swap implementation in Vlad's answer for an example.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yes.. It's truly what I want to mean

Comment: Take a look at the answer, I amended it to include a c++ use of `swap(float&,...`

Comment: thank you so much... because of my english, I can't explain clearly :)  thank you!

Comment: Your English is fine, keep at it, glad I could help.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: If your C++ code compiles it is because it is using the standard library [swap function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), probably brought in by the `<iostream>` header. It is not using your swap function, because an `int` will not bind to a `float&`. If you remove `using namespace std;` (and properly qualify `cout` as `std::cout` and `endl` as `std::endl`), it will not compile.

Comment: @DracudaKid I removed `namespace std;` to insure there wasn't ambiguity in which `swap` was used. Give it a try.

Comment: Using a C-style cast here is resulting in the equivalent of a `reinterpret_cast`. This code has undefined behavior on the line `float temp=a`. The code in this answer, while it does compile, is really not a good idea at all.

Comment: note: both of these solutions violate strict aliasing, and may give bogus results or further UB if `int` and `float` are different sizes, or of the int representation is not a valid float representation.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm not sure if you have followed along, but it is well established that casting from `int` to `float reference` is **not** an optimal way to do this. The code is the result of specific constraints from the OP. Why we are still passing `int` to a `float swap` is still unclear. How would you recommend improving the process within the constraints?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The constraints make a solution with well-defined behavior impossible. OP appears to want this, for some reason. My comment was more directed at other readers who might stumble on this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to swap temporary objects (created due to using the casting). that moreover would be deleted after exiting from the swap. You may not bind temporary objects with non-constant references. So there is no sense in such a call. It is entire unclear why you are trying to cast the both integers to float that to swap them. Why do not swap integers themselves?

Write the function like

```
void swap( int &a, int &b )
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Take into account that there is already standard function `std::swap`

If you want to write swap function in C then it will look like

```
void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: I just want to use swap (float,float) 
because I also need to swap float types

Comment: @DracudaKid You may overload the function in C++. So you will have two functions with the same name. Or you can write a template function the same way as the standard function or use the standard function swap itself. In C you have to rename one of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the array using the pointers(*). While passing only you have to give the ampersand(&). Use this following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int* a, int *b){
float temp=*a;
*a=*b;
*b=temp;
}
main()
{
 int a=10, b=5;
 swap(&a, &b);
 printf("%d \t %d\n",a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you should be using `std::swap`, or if you prefer you can write your own template that will swap any two values.

```
template <typename T>
void swap(T & a, T & b)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10, b = 5;
    swap(a, b);
    std::cout << a << " \t " << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What you are trying to accomplish (treating an `int` as a `float`) is going to result in undefined behavior -- it might work on your compiler but it could easily break on a different compiler or architecture.  You can use `reinterpret_cast` to force this behavior if you *really* want to.